# How to create and run xml file for multiple testNG classes in same package?

Tags: xml, selenium, testng

How to create and run .xml file for multiple testNG classes in same package?

I have two classes in the same package and I want to run both of them one after another. I guess we can do it by creating single .xml file. How can I do it?

Comment: visit testng website it has all the information you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

1. Lets Assume you have a Class named `Class 1` as follows:

   ```
   package Q44015837_prioritize_multiclasses;

   import org.testng.annotations.Test;

   public class Class1 
   {
       @Test
       void p1() 
       {
           System.out.println("Class1 p1");
       }
   }
   ```
2. Execute `Class1` as `TestNG Test`.
3. Convert the `Class1` through `Convert to TestNG`.
4. `testng.xml` gets generated within your project space.
5. The `testng.xml` will look as follows:

```html
<suite name="Suite">
  <test name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="Q44015837_prioritize_multiclasses.Class1"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

6. Now lets assume we have to execute another class named `Class2` which is as follows:

   ```
   package Q44015837_prioritize_multiclasses;

   import org.testng.annotations.Test;

   public class Class2 
   {
       @Test
       void p2()
       {
           System.out.println("Class2 p2");
       }
   }
   ```

   7. Now, we will simply add the entry of `Class2` within the `testng.xml` as follows:

```html
<suite name="Suite">
  <test name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="Q44015837_prioritize_multiclasses.Class1"/>
      <class name="Q44015837_prioritize_multiclasses.Class2"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

> Note that the following have been added:
>
> **`<class name="Q44015837_prioritize_multiclasses.Class2"/>`**

8. Now execute the `testng.xml` as a `TestNG Suite`
9. You will observe both the class gets executed.

   Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with followings.

```
<suite name="testSuite">
  <test name="Test1" preserve-order="true">
    <classes>
      <class name="packageName.class1"/>
      <class name="packageName.class2"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```